# Change path in Rake file task prerequisites

Tags: ruby, rake, rake-task, rakefile

I have a hardcoded file task

```
file 'feed.json' => 'lib/feed.rb'
```

How can I use match patterns

```
file '*.json' => 'lib/$1.rb' # Like this (this is pseudocode)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could this do the trick?

```rb
source_files = Rake::FileList.new("lib/*.md")
task :default => :json
task :json => source_files.ext(".rb")

rule ".json" => ".rb" do |t|
  # here what you need to be done
end
```

To Wacht this [video](https://avdi.codes/rake-part-2-file-lists/) could help.